# Как написать Sql запрос в Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Есть такой запрос`

```
select * 
from products 
where City=IIF(City=@city,City,IIF(@city='',City,'')) 
AND  product_name=IIF(product_name Like @product_name, product_name, IIF(@product_name='',product_name,'')) 
AND price between @price_from and @price_to 
AND  cat_name=IIF(cat_name=@category,cat_name,IIF(@category='',cat_name,''))
```

Как его можно записать в Entity Framework ?

Comment: с помощью `Linq`

Answer (score 0):

```
        using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
        { 
            var blogNames = context.Database.SqlQuery<List<Products>>( 
                               "select * from products where City=IIF(City=@city,City,IIF(@city='',City,'')) AND  
    product_name=IIF(product_name Like @product_name, product_name, IIF(@product_name='',product_name,'')) AND price between @price_from and @price_to AND  cat_name=IIF(cat_name=@category,cat_name,
IIF(@category='',cat_name,''))");
        }
```

Теоретически Вы можете использовать это так, но лучше использовать ef linq запрос или создайте хранимую процедуру и вызовите ее, что бы не хардкодить запрос

Comment: Where(e => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(category) || e.cat_name == category)

Comment: Я имел ввиду это cat_name=IIF(cat_name=@category,cat_name,
IIF(@category='',cat_name,''))") как написать?

Comment: уверяю Вас, тоже самое у меня и написано, только в более правильной форме